# Where is the number value of <li> tag located?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

So if I run this code the result it's

1. a
2. b
3. c

```html
<ol>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
</ol>
```

I'd like to know how can I find or where are the 1, 2, 3 numbers defined in the DOM?

I ask this bc I want to set them as a key for elements in a map in reactJS.

Also if you guys can give me tips on how to find strings in the DOM thatd be great! Im kinda new at this! :/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The  tells the DOM that what follows is to displayed as a ordered list. Such as numbers or alphabets. The elements are not in the DOM tree but they are displayed on the screen.

The list items can be selected as a zero indexed array. So 6 items would be indexed to 5 since the first element is zero.